# Manual JSDoc comments — creating a template

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

I've been asked to create a JSDoc template for our developers to document their ES6 code. I'm not sure which of the [70 or so @ block tags](http://usejsdoc.org/) would be useful and whether I'd be bogging down the developers with excess documentation requirements. The [documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-es2015-classes.html#documenting-a-simple-class) gives very simple examples, which really aren't helpful.

Looking for real world experience of the set of block tags most useful to experienced JavaScript developers. When I ask ours, they just say: "Whatever you decide!", but calling them *experienced JavaScript developers* approaches a 3:1 lie:phrase ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the following provides enough information without burdening the developers.

For classes:

```
/**
 * The XYZ class description .... In this class function1, and
 * function2 are intended for external use.
 *
 * @author        ...
 * @version       1.0
 * @see           XYZ.function1
 * @see           XYZ.function2
 **/
```

For constructors:

```
/**
 * The constructor ...
 *
 * @author        ...
 * @constructor
 * @this          instance of XYZ
 **/
```

For private members in a constructor:

```
/** @private **/ this.x = 1;
/** @private **/ this.y = 2;
/** @private **/ this.z = 3;
```

For functions:

```
/**
 * The function ...
 *
 * @author        ...
 * @param         {type|otherType} X - description
 * @param         {type=} Y - optional, description
 * @param         {type=3} Z - default value, description
 * @return        {type} - description, omit if nothing returned
 * @this          instance of XYZ, or XYZ class for static functions
 * @private       omit if not private
 * @see           XYZ.function, provide if another function is relevant
 * @throws        exception, omit if no exceptions are thrown
 **/
```